# Whats wrong with this re-throwing exception?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

I'm using wcf Service to insert data to DB and my service crashes saying exception un-handled. I'm trying to pass on exception from one WCF service method to other WCF method and from there throwing exception to client.

Here is My code:

Data Inserting Method of WCF Service: method to insert data to DB

```
public int insertStatements(SqlCommand cmd)
{           
  Try
  { 
   //insert data to the db

  }
 catch(SqlException ex)
 {
   if (ex.Number == 2627) // if unique key constraint error
    {
     throw new FaultException( "error reason", new FaultCode("Error Code: "); 
    }
    else
    {
      throw new FaultException("DB error: ", new FaultCode("Error Code: " +);
    }
}
 catch (FaultException ex)
 {
     throw new FaultException("Unknown Error",new FaultCode("Unknown Error"));
 }
 }
```

WCF Insert location method, which is service exposed method(Public)

```
public int insertLocation (string name)
{
try
 {
     // this method communicates with client
    dataconnection.insertStatements(cmd);  

 }    
  catch
  {
     throw; // Here i'm getting error
  }
}
```

in my client: winform Application

```
 try
 {
    AreaDataServicesClient DataObject = new AreaDataServicesClient("BasicHttpBinding_IAreaDataServices");
     int rowsAffected = DataObject.InsertProvince(ProvinceObject.AreaName, ProvinceObject.AreaKm);
      return rowsAffected;
  }
  catch(FaultException ex)
  {
     messagebox.show("erro occured");
  }
```

This is the Error i get:
**"An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in EMSDataServices.dll but was not handled in user code"**

Why service method does not pass exception to the client.

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: @BJMyers i mentioned it in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found it. There was nothing wrong with the code. i was running the services on debug mode and in exception setting 'break at this point if user code is unhandled' was checked,so it was stopping the service to perform further action and client was crashing due to no response from service.

i unchecked it and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

@Mohsin, catch (FaultException ex) in insertStatements is useless. It will never catch your exception. because you are throwing the exception outside the method. You should handle the exception somewhere which is re-thrown. That you can do it in the insertLocation method. See the bellow modified code.

```
public int insertLocation(string name)
        {
            try
            {
                dataconnection.insertStatements(cmd);
            }
            catch (FaultException ex)
            {
                // you should handle the exception here. Do not retrow here too. Otherwise you may need to handle somewhere else again.
            }
        }
        public int insertStatements(SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            try
            {
                //insert data to the db

            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Number == 2627) // if unique key constraint error
                {
                    throw new FaultException("error reason", new FaultCode("Error Code: ");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new FaultException("DB error: ", new FaultCode("Error Code: ");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: i want to handle exception in the UI layer of my Client. thats why i'm throwing it. i will show message box there that this error has occurred.

Comment: Inside Faulty exception catch block just take whatever exception detail you want and show it in the message box. This is called exception handling. You can't just throw the exception and leave.

Comment: that catch block is in wcf service. i need to return it to the client

Comment: @Mohsin, then do not throw the exception. you can return the entire object to the client as an exception object. OR create a custom object and fill the exception details.

Comment: why not? if i don't throw exception to the client. then there i will have to make a lot more checks. Whats wrong with this code? why it won't handle exception.

Comment: Finally when you want to reply to the client, there must be a code to send this exception. So you should handle the exception. As you said there will be an internal code which wraps up this exception and throws the whole exception to the client. But as your error says, you should handle your exception code

Comment: i found it. There was nothing wrong with the code. i was running the services on debug mode and in exception setting break at this point if user is not handling code was checked. i unchecked it and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The line marked `///Here i'm getting the error` is a `throw` statement. That's exactly what it's supposed to do. It's taking the exception which has been caught (because it's in a `try`) and making it unhandled again, as if it had never been caught.

That's what you might do if you wanted to log or inspect the exception and then let it bubble up. In this case it's exactly the same as removing the entire try/catch.

This:

```
public int insertLocation (string name)
{
    try
    {
        dataconnection.insertStatements(cmd);  
    }    
    catch
    {
        throw; // Here i'm getting error
    }
}
```

is the same as this:

```
public int insertLocation (string name)
{
    dataconnection.insertStatements(cmd);  
}
```

Comment: Also, if you're going to throw a FaultException, check out this documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultexception(v=vs.110).aspx. If you only pass the error code from SQL that's going to be harder to debug. You could pass the actual message from the SqlException.